# Java servlet and class with static initializer

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a class which my servlet instantiates on each page request.  That class has a static initializer, a static variable and the rest contains non-static public or private members, a constructor, etc.

Is this safe?  I don't want the static initializer to be called but only **once** throughout the lifecycle of my servlet.

Using Tomcat. I understand that each time the class is loaded by a Class Loader, the static initializer will be called. Should this be a concern for me (using tomcat) based on my requirement?

Comment: If you have used the Singleton design pattern, you shouldn't be worried it

Comment: @eliasah What does singleton have to do with this? He clearly says "which my servlet instantiates on each page request".

Comment: @Kayaman The Singleton is a useful Design Pattern for allowing only one instance of your class, but common mistakes can inadvertently allow more than one instance to be created. Just because a container will customarily only create a single instance of a servlet does not make it a singleton. You can create one instance of any class -- that's not what a singleton is. A singleton is a class that cannot have more than one instance.

Comment: @eliasah Singleton is a commonly abused design pattern by unexperienced programmers. I didn't ask you to explain the pattern to  me, I asked why you brought it up as it had nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no problems, except if you modify the static variable since it'll be shared by all the requests. You will have concurrency issues if you do any decisions based on that variable.

Static initialization happens at class loading time, so that'll only happen once.

Answer (score 0):

unless you maintain state in this second class you should not be worried about number of instantiations. A static initializer would serve just fine. There is no hard way to enforce "only once throughout the lifetime" behavior.

There are easy and plenty of hacks to turn your singleton to a multiton so I wouldnt worry about it. If you are a die hard fanatic for it use Spring or Pico else just dont maintain state in the second class only do stateless conversations with your servlet and all will be well.